# Word or Phrase for events that don't fall into other categories

Tags: phrase-requests

We have regular events that happen every week or month. **Storytime** or **Movie Night**. We have other events that might be a one off. Most events fall into this later category, however I'd like to have a word to describe them... The best I've come up with is "special events" but that implies that the regular events aren't special.

Comment: "non-repeated"?

Comment: are these events spontaneous or planned?

Comment: These are all planned events, we have 60-80 events per month. Our software can show particular tags, but it can't show all events excluding specific tags, so basically we need to come up with a tag for "not storytime or movie or other regular event"

Comment: Requests to help name something (such as a tag) are out of scope. Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Have you looked at other calendars? What about Google's approach e.g. "Does not repeat" vs "Every ..."

Answer (score 2):

You may consider ***nonrecurrent***.

> [**nonrecurrent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonrecurrent): not recurring
>
> [**recur**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recur): to occur again after an interval :  occur time after
>   time

For a more informal term, you may consider *one-time* or *one-off* events. The latter is already used in your question.